HTTP: Under what circumstances does `Content-Disposition:attachment` produce a 'Save as' dialog?
In principle, an HTML response can set Content-Disposition to attachment, and the browser should then present a 'Save as' dialog, to allow the response body to be saved at the client (see Content-Disposition at MDN).
In practice, this doesn't seem to work if the response is to a POST request (without a lot of extra work), and at least one reference I've found claims that this only works for GET requests.
So what's going on here? Is it true that this only works for GET requests and, if so, why? Is this browser-specific, or is it specified somewhere?
